# Ejection charges on Dnepr Rocket tube?

Tags: launch, rockets, propulsion

The Dnepr rocket was initially developed for use as a ballistic missile. Therefore it was developed with an explosive charge that fired the rocket out of the ground and into the air, followed by the main engine ignition right above ground.

[image]
<sup>Graphic showing the launch sequence</sup>

Why did the Dnepr rocket still use the silo tube even after it became a commercial launcher? Wouldn't it be cheaper to stop using the ejection charges and just launch it from Baikonur?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In order to launch it from Baikonur you need to build launch facility. Launch pad, even for simple rockets is expensive thing. It is much simpler and cheaper to use existing infrastructure.

Also - almost certainly, Dnepr will not be launched more, because Kosmotras company was Russian-Ukrainian joint, and now there are too much tensions between Russia and Ukraine